# Dynamically parsing Jade Content

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, compilation, pug

I have a scenario in which I need to parse JADE from a database (MongoDB).

I have created a Data Access Class with a 'method' findByTitle to return the required JADE data and it works.

```
app.get('/something', function (req, res) {
  blogProvider.findByTitle('Structure', function(error, blog){
    if (error) {
        console.log('Trying to find blog by title, an error has occured ' + error);
    } else {
        var jade = require('jade');
        var fn = jade.compile(blog.body, {filename:'structure.jade'});
        var html = fn();
        res.send(html);
    }
});
```

});

The above successfully compiles JADE on the fly from the DB and returns it correctly. The issue I am having is if the JADE in the DB has extends or includes (which I need in my case), they are not compiled ...

Short of manually storing all the extends and includes and naturally fixing all the indentation, there does not seem to be a way to 'compile' the JADE and get the compiler to bring in the extensions and the includes.

As you can see above I tried to give a valid but 'dummy' file so that the compiler might find the other required files. I have looked through the docs and not found a way around this, any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

I found a work around, not exactly a full solution. Which is basically to create a template (of a template), something like

```
extends layout

block append content
 include includes/header
 div.container
    !{someContent}
    include agile
 include includes/footer
```

And then send the html in (above in the question) as follows:

```
res.render('someTemplate.jade', {someContent: html});
```

Still not ideal as not all the content is dynamic. If anyone finds a better solution, please let me know ...